# IR Range sensor Rviz Issue

Tags: rviz, sensor-msgs, plugin, ir, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having difficulty displaying the range visualization plugin inside of rviz.

I have followed this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/IR%20Ranger

Furthermore, I have sensor output on the "range_data/range" topic from the arduino with Indigo.

Rviz has a plugin for Range topics listed.

However it appears that when I add the range topic into rviz I encounter an error for the header_frame not matching the fixed_frame.  I resolved this by adding a static transform between my fixed frame[map] and my header frame[ir_ranger]; this remedies the plugin error message within rviz however no ir range sensors are shown visually inside rviz.
I can not see the IR sensors(cones?) on my map.

```
Range topic output:

Without any objects:
---
header: 
  seq: 456
  stamp: 
    secs: 1441714744
    nsecs: 397090908
  frame_id: /ir_ranger
radiation_type: 1
field_of_view: 0.00999999977648
min_range: 0.0299999993294
max_range: 0.40000000596
range: 254.0
---
With object:
---
header: 
  seq: 537
  stamp: 
    secs: 1441714962
    nsecs: 24221998
  frame_id: /ir_ranger
radiation_type: 1
field_of_view: 0.00999999977648
min_range: 0.0299999993294
max_range: 0.40000000596
range: 22.0
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217242/ir-range-sensor-rviz-issue/) by [russellc](https://answers.ros.org/users/23787/russellc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-09-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-09-08**:
Can you paste a rostopic echo of your sensor output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure this is your issue, but looking at the documentation of [sensor_msgs/Range](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html), the comments on `min_range`, `max_range` and `range` seem to suggest that any value `< min_range`, or `> max_range` "*should be discarded*":

```
float32 range           # range data [m]
                        # (Note: values < range_min or > range_max
                        # should be discarded)
                        # Fixed distance rangers only output -Inf or +Inf.
                        # -Inf represents a detection within fixed distance.
                        # (Detection too close to the sensor to quantify)
                        # +Inf represents no detection within the fixed distance.
                        # (Object out of range)
```

The code in [rviz/default_plugin/range_display.cpp](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/391462561d2c4c7e25eea5cc42c01171b1a363f8/src/rviz/default_plugin/range_display.cpp#L135-L142) seems to follow that recommendation (although not explicitly):

```
  float displayed_range = 0.0;
  if(msg->min_range <= msg->range && msg->range <= msg->max_range)
  {
    displayed_range = msg->range;
  }
  else if(msg->min_range == msg->max_range)  // Fixed distance ranger
  {
    if(msg->range < 0 && !std::isfinite(msg->range))     // NaNs and +Inf return false here: both of those should have 0.0 as the range
    {
      displayed_range = msg->min_range; // -Inf, display the detectable range
    }
  }
```

The two messages you posted (`range: 254.0` and `range: 22.0`) seem to fall outside both `if` clauses (not between `min` and `max` range, and also `min != max`), leaving `displayed_range` at `0.0`.

I think there is a cone in your RViz, it just has 0 length.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [russellc](https://answers.ros.org/users/23787/russellc/) on 2015-09-08**:
Thanks gvdhoorn, it was my issue.  I modified my range values and it now shows up, albeit not as a 3D cone but as a 2d line emitter(view setting?)...none the less, solved!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-09**:
Well cone width if based on `displayed_range` and `field_of_view` ([here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/391462561d2c4c7e25eea5cc42c01171b1a363f8/src/rviz/default_plugin/range_display.cpp#L156)), so there might be something not entirely correct with your publisher.

**Comment by [russellc](https://answers.ros.org/users/23787/russellc/) on 2015-09-09**:
Yes, I ended up adjusting my field_of_view setting to compensate for the new values and now I have the cone object emitter. Thanks.